# Cannot detect small shapes using findContours

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to detect specific types of shapes - triangle, square, circle - in a binary image using cv2.findContours, and to color each type with differnt color.
The following code works for big shapes, but it's not working for small shapes - about 10*10 px.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.imread('1.jpg',0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)

contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    print len(approx)
    if len(approx)==3:
        print "triangle"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(122,212,78),-1)
    elif len(approx)==4:
        print "square"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(94,234,255),-1)
    elif len(approx) > 15:
        print "circle"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(220,152,91),-1)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the image I used:[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK4F1.jpg)

and the result:[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKfKv.jpg)

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"The second argument in cv2.approxPolyDP is called epsilon, which is maximum distance from contour to approximated contour. It is an accuracy parameter. A wise selection of epsilon is needed to get the correct output."*

The Output of the same code with the following change-

```
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,.03*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
```

[image]

Comment: thank for your replay. I check your solution and it does detect the small squares and rectangles, but is does not detect circles at all.

Comment: I changed "elif len(approx) > 15" for a circle to "elif len(approx) > 7". Then it detects the circles, but it could be a as well a variety of shapes other than a circle.

Comment: Ya, i just gave an example. Try different values for the coefficient to figure out what fits best for the problem.